# Register domain using Cloud Domains

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to purchase a new domain using Google's `Cloud Domains` service for a GCP project (it is a webapplication running in the `Appengine`). I was following the [quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/domains/docs/getting-started), but the `Register Domain` button is disabled for me. When hovered over, it says

> Quota for domain registrations has been reached

eventhough I haven't ever registered a domain. The `Quotas` page states that the quota limit for registering domains is set to 0, but I can't change it. Billing is enabled for the project.

Can anyone help, what do I have to set somewhere to obtain a domain? Or is there a more optimal way of registering a custom domain to an `Appengine` application without using `Google Domains` (it is not available in my region)?

Comment: I suspect that cloud domains is also not available in your region.  :(

Comment: Can you please mention the quickstart link you are referring to and the region of your App Engine? As a first step can you try going to [this page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/domains.googleapis.com/quotas), then expand the Domain registrations tab and edit the Domain registrations quota limit to a value more than 0 and less than 5?

Comment: @gaefan cloud domains should be available anywhere where gcp is available

Comment: @Prabir I embedded the quickstart link in the question. The region of the App engine is europe-west. I visited the page you linked, but the registrations quota limit is set to 0 and says it cannot be edited

Answer (score 1):

To view quotas or request quota increases, Identity and Access Management (IAM) principals need one of the following [Cloud Domains roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-domains-roles):

To check quotas for a project you should require a project role(Cloud Domains Viewer (roles/domains.viewer)).

Modify quota, request additional quota you should require project role Cloud Domains Admin (roles/domains.admin Or Project Owner role (roles/owner), Project Editor role (roles/editor) ).
For more information refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/domains/quotas).

Please note that requesting a quota increase can take from 24 to 48 hours for approval. Refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/domains/quotas#requesting-additional-quota) for more information.